# Why does an increase in temperature decrease the electrode potential?

Tags: electrochemistry

According to the Nernst equation, the electrode potential $E$ is
$$E = E^\circ - \frac{RT}{nF}\ln\frac{[\ce{M}]}{[\ce{M^{$n$+}}]}$$

Question is, why? Assuming a simple galvanic cell, we know that in general if the temperature is increased, there should be more collisions of the solution with the electrode, resulting in a higher accumulation of the metal ions on the electrode. It should also make it easier for the metal atoms in the electrode to leave the electrode and go into the solution.

Also, if temperature reaches zero, the reaction should stop altogether as there would be no more collisions and no more potential difference should be developed on the electrodes. Yet according to the Nernst equation if temperature reaches zero, maximum standard electrode potential would be reached instead. Where am I going wrong?